# Run Windows Store .Net app on Linux/Mono

Tags: .net, windows, mono, windows-store-apps

Does Moto support to run Windows Store app? If so, is there a document for how to deploy Windows store app on Mono? Thanks.

BTW, for Moto, I mean => http://www.mono-project.com/, if there are other recommendation for .Net simulator on Linux which supports running Windows Store app, it will be great.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Almost impossible at this moment as Windows Runtime is not yet portable to other OS.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi, then what is the capability of Moto? Does Mono declare being able to run Windows app on Linux? :)

Comment: it is a clone of .NET Framework so you can see only those apps are portable. General Windows apps are not portable to Linux.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi, I mean Windows Store App written in .Net, is it ok?

Comment: Windows Store apps use Windows Runtime and C#, but that's not .NET Framework at all.

Comment: @LexLi, nice comments, and vote up. But .Net also use underlying Windows Runtime, correct? :)

Comment: Windows Runtime was first introduced in Windows 8, but .NET Framework was first announced in 2000 (http://corefx.strikingly.com) so you can see whether there is any relationship.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi, so .Net has no dependencies on Windows Runtime? Thanks.

Comment: .NET Framework only depends on native Windows API.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi, vote up. What are differences between Windows Runtime and Windows API? I feel short of such kinds of knowledge. :)

Comment: @LexLi, if you could add a reply, I will mark it as answered to benefit people who has similar issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Store apps are running on Windows Runtime (shipped with Windows 8), not .NET Framework. Therefore, to port them to other OS, there must be an implementation of the Windows Runtime.

Mono is merely an open source implementation of the .NET Framework, so you cannot run Windows Store apps on Mono.

You might get a better view of Windows Runtime and .NET Framework from this thread,

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155521/what-is-the-difference-between-windows-8-winrt-and-windows-rt

[image]

Comment: Thanks Lex Li, vote up and mark your reply as answer. :)